# Problems to import json with VueJs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, config

So, I'm trying to import a json file to be able to set some params in my application. The code I'm using to import my json is:

```
import json from './json/config.json'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            URL_FILE_IMPORT: json.fileImport,
        }
    }
}
```

... and my **config.json** is very simple so far:

```
{
    "fileImport": "<my_url_goes_here>",
}
```

The problem is that I'm facing this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors


This relative module was not found:

* ./json/config.json in ./src/services/config.js
```

But I have access to the file, if I click in the `./json/config.json` path.

I've seen that there are some differences between some vue.js versions about the json configuration. I'm not 100% sure how to see the version I'm using, but my `@vue/cli-service` is version 4.2.2. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

---

So, I've found my solution. It was very simple, I just needed to use

```
const jsonData = require('../json/config.json');
```

... and with this I can access `jsonData.fileImport`

Comment: You can instead use `fetch()` to retrieve and parse the contents of the JSON file instead. Otherwise you will need to use a loader made specifically to import JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Маке sure the path is correct, if you make import in file ./src/services/config.js with path "./json/data.json" it will look for json in ./src/services/json. Where exactly is your folder /json, if it is in src folder then import should be "../json/data.json". Usually there is alias in web-pack "@" which is to "/src", then import will be "@/json/config.json"

Comment: Thanks man, my mistake to put the other names, it's because I've tried with a lot of name and paths and made a little mistake whit them. I've tried  "_@/json/config.json_" but I wasn't able to get it as well. I just solved the question, but thanks anyway